# thread synchronization without using flag variable

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I have implemented producer-consumer thread synchronization problem  through pthread as per my assignment but my teacher rejected by saying that use of flag variable is not acceptable as it is inefficient way. Can anybody suggest how it can be implemented without use of flag variable.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
pthread_mutex_t count_mutex     = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t  condition_var   = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

void *consumer();
void *producer();
int  count = 0;
#define COUNT_DONE  10
int flag=0;
main()
{
   pthread_t thread1, thread2;
   pthread_create( &thread1, NULL, &producer, NULL);
   pthread_create( &thread2, NULL, &consumer,NULL);

   pthread_join( thread1, NULL);
   pthread_join( thread2, NULL);

   exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void *consumer()
{
   for(;;)
   {
      // Lock mutex and then wait for signal to relase mutex
      pthread_mutex_lock( &count_mutex );

      pthread_cond_wait( &condition_var, &count_mutex );

      while (count!=0)
      { 
      count--;
      printf("Counter value consumer: %d\n",count);
      }
      pthread_mutex_unlock( &count_mutex );

      if(count == 0) 
      {
      return NULL; 

      } 
    }
}

void *producer()
{
    for(;;)
    {
       pthread_mutex_lock( &count_mutex );

       if( count==COUNT_DONE  )
       {
          flag=1;
         pthread_cond_signal( &condition_var );

       }
       else if(flag==0)
       {
          count++;
          printf("Counter value producer: %d\n",count);
       }

       pthread_mutex_unlock( &count_mutex );
          if(count==0) return (NULL);

    }

}
```

Comment: Note that the signatures of your thread-start functions are incorrect.  Each should accept an argument of type `void *` (even if they ignore it).

Comment: Count appears to track the number of unconsumed items.  If so, couldn't it become 0 once the first (and so far, only) item produced gets consumed, and everybody shuts down?

Comment: Global variable `flag` is read only by function `producer()`, and set only by its initializer and by that function.  It certainly doesn't need to be global.  I don't really see why you need it at all; better control flow in `producer()` could do the same job.

Comment: agree, flag is required only in producer thread.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the consumer thread is blocked until signaled via the condition variable, that it does not examine variable `count` until after being signaled, that the producer does not signal until it has incremented `count` to `COUNT_DONE`, and that the producer does not afterward increment `count` again, this version of `producer()` yields the same result more simply:

```
void *producer()
{
    pthread_mutex_lock( &count_mutex );

    for(; count < COUNT_DONE; count++)
    {
        printf("Counter value producer: %d\n",count);
    }

    pthread_cond_signal( &condition_var );
    pthread_mutex_unlock( &count_mutex );

    return NULL;    
}
```

Although this version does not wait for the consumer to finish before it finishes itself, it also does not go into an infinite loop if the consumer should die without consuming `count` back to zero.

Comment: Do note, however, that it's not *quite* true that the consumer thread is blocked until signaled.  Spurrious wakeups are possible, and if the consumer should happen to experience a spurrious wakeup before the producer locks the mutex then it will run *before* the producer produces anything.

Answer (score 0):

In a classic producer consumer solution there will be two conditional variables to signal both  produce and consume threads. A modified implementation is below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
pthread_mutex_t count_mutex     = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t  condition_var_produce   = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t  condition_var_consume   = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

void *consumer();
void *producer();
int  count = 0;
#define COUNT_DONE  10
main()
{
   pthread_t thread1, thread2;
   pthread_create( &thread1, NULL, &producer, NULL);
   pthread_create( &thread2, NULL, &consumer,NULL);

   pthread_join( thread1, NULL);
   pthread_join( thread2, NULL);

   exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void *consumer()
{
    static int numberOfIterations = 1;
    while(numberOfIterations--);
    {
      pthread_mutex_lock( &count_mutex );

      while(count!=COUNT_DONE)
              pthread_cond_wait( &condition_var_consume, &count_mutex );

      while (count!=0)
      {
              printf("Counter value consumer: %d\n",count);
              count--;
      }
      pthread_cond_signal(&condition_var_produce);
      pthread_mutex_unlock( &count_mutex );

      if(count == 0)
      {
        return NULL;
      }
    }
}

void *producer()
{
    static int numberOfIterations = 1;
    while(numberOfIterations--);
    {
       pthread_mutex_lock( &count_mutex );

       while (count!=0)
              pthread_cond_wait( &condition_var_produce, &count_mutex );

       while(count!=COUNT_DONE  )
        {
             count++;
             printf("Counter value producer: %d\n",count);
        }

         pthread_cond_signal( &condition_var_consume );
         pthread_mutex_unlock( &count_mutex );
    }

}
```